# Using jQuery sortable inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to load [some html](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8yX/) in an iframe and make certain elements in that html page sortable:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FR2vr/)

**JS:**

```
var _iframe = $('iframe');
var containment = _iframe.contents().find( "modules" );
if(containment.data('sortable')) containment.sortable('destroy');

containment.sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('STOP: I am never called');
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('START: I am called with a delay!');
    },
    containment: containment,
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    items: "> module",
    delay: 10,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 10000
});
```

This causes some unexpected behavior like **delayed start event** and **no stop event** at all

The problem occurs only if the content is inside an iframe. [Here's a version](http://jsfiddle.net/wnnyb/) without iframe (and how it should work)

Try to sort the elements [in this version](http://jsfiddle.net/FR2vr/) (and keep you console open)

Comment: try adding the plugin initialization code inside the iframe's `dom ready`

Comment: no doesn't work and wasn't the problem. the iframe is completed loaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only working solution is to put the code in the iframe. Maybe the iframe doesn't like it when it's parent clean up his room...