# jQuery Sortable in iFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an iFrame with jQuery sortable content. All codes are done and work but when I draging an item to change it, Mouse cannot work and pause until move to out of iFrame, Now the item is on dragging state.

How can i solve this? I think this problem is with mouse event on iFrame.

JS:

```
     var d = function (a, b) {
        b.children().each(function () {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return b;
    };

$($("#frame").contents().find('body')).find("#DragAndDrop tbody").sortable({
            helper: d,
            revert: "invalid",
            cursor: "move",
            opacity: 0.7,
            containment: "parent",
            items: "tr.DragAndDrop",
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function(e, ui){
                ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="./theme.html" id="frame" style="width: 100%; height: 1020px; " frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

The content of sortable is Table with DragAndDrop id. All tr with class DragAndDrop should sort with jquery sortable.

**Update:**

This is the simple demo for iframe. Just help me for do sortable the contents of iFrame. I just want to khow how you do this. http://jsfiddle.net/saeedhbi/vRbM5/2/

**Update 2:**

Problem is solved. You can find solution at this: [Creating a jQuery UI sortable in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369708/creating-a-jquery-ui-sortable-in-an-iframe)

Comment: You have any code or an example for us?

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.

Comment: Does your sortable code have to run in an iframe?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Please Just help for sortable this demo for iframe. http://jsfiddle.net/saeedhbi/vRbM5/2/

Comment: @saeedhbi - If you look at your developer console you'll see `Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.` I assume that your "real" site suffers from the same problem. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript for more information on `Same Origin Policy`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks. but my real site do the sortable. I just have problem with this part. The Mouse at iFrame.

Comment: OK. I've established that the code "should" work. However, based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274439/using-jquery-sortable-inside-an-iframe it appears that you will have to put the jQuery code for the iframe in the iframe.

Comment: Also, if you want to be able to connect the iframe sortable with the other one then I think you will run into problems.

Comment: It'd be better if you answer your question and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Problem is solved. You can find solution at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369708/creating-a-jquery-ui-sortable-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[jeffery-to](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311572/jeffery-to) solved my problem. We should dynamically add jQuery and jQuery UI to the iframe and load jQuery UI after jQuery loaded.

```
$('iframe')
    .load(function() {
        var win = this.contentWindow,
            doc = win.document,
            body = doc.body,
            jQueryLoaded = false,
            jQuery;

        function loadJQueryUI() {
            body.removeChild(jQuery);
            jQuery = null;

            win.jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js',
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: true,
                success: function () {
                    win.jQuery('.sortable').sortable();
                }
            });
        }

        jQuery = doc.createElement('script');

        // based on https://gist.github.com/getify/603980
        jQuery.onload = jQuery.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ((jQuery.readyState && jQuery.readyState !== 'complete' && jQuery.readyState !== 'loaded') || jQueryLoaded) {
                return false;
            }
            jQuery.onload = jQuery.onreadystatechange = null;
            jQueryLoaded = true;
            loadJQueryUI();
        };

        jQuery.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
        body.appendChild(jQuery);
    })
    .prop('src', 'iframe-test.html');
```

Read more inforamtion about this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240770/2855673